# No recent files listed in "Open Recent" menu

Tags: dreamweaver

Running Dreamweaver CS5.5, recently opened files are not being stored in the recent file list menu (File --> Open Recent) on my installation of Dreamweaver. Is there a setting I can enable to turn this on?

Comment: do you use any kind of cleaner for your computer like ccleaner or some third party software?

Comment: I do, but that doesn't explain how the list is *never* populated.

Comment: ok if your are using ccleaner it will erase all of you recent history for your application. Just double check the software whatever you are using, there might be some option which might help you.

Comment: No, you don't understand. The list _never_ gets populated. There's nothing for CCleaner to clean. _it is always empty_

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I had the same problem and dreamweaver tells me to clear my browser history in preferences and add a new browser.  This didn't work.  But this video will clear it up. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRB3fvASnCM  except that in this video he suggests deleting the file, because he wants to clear his history.
If you need to rebuild your file.  Go into the preferences he talks about, scroll down until you find the command and take out all the junk, just leaving the safari (or Explorer) commands. Dreamweaver will start building your `recently open' files.